# Google login in my site

Tags: gmail

I want my website user should be login through fbconnect or gmail account.
fbconnect is simple, but i am not able to do with gmail.
Can anybody please let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To login with a google account you need to use [openID](http://openid.net/)

Google Docs on their implementation: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

It could be easy to solve if you use library that implements open ID for you.

- Java Version http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/
- .net Version http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/
- List of Libraries for various programming languages http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Google OpenID API](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) (as this site does)

Answer (score 3):

Google are an [OpenID](http://openid.net/add-openid) provider.