# I have an php website with login form and I want every visitors can able to login into my website using their gmail account

Tags: php, authentication, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google login in my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810911/google-login-in-my-site)

I have an php website with login form and I want every visitors can able to login into my website using their gmail account???

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at [OpenID](http://openid.net/), it will let users choose a variety of common login sources

See here for additional detail regarding implementation:

[PHP - How to implement user registrationg using OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795122/php-how-to-implement-user-registrationg-using-openid/7795148#7795148)

Answer (score 0):

OAuth could let you use the gmail services, once the user gives you the authorization to do it