# How to use openID to login in a site with another site's account?

Tags: php, openid

I want to know how does SO registers users if they have only a `gmail` account and don't ask for any information.

in a word, how it is possible to login with google or facebook account in another website using `openID`.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to ask; are you looking at something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4874186/899126)?

Comment: Voting to close own question when a dup is found: +1 `:)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow allows you to register using your Google account, meaning as long as you're logged in via Google at the time you register/log in you won't need to supply a username/password. Stack Overflow will then get some needed information from your Google account after you authorize it to.

Here's a decent run-down of the process: http://qpleple.com/how-to-make-people-login-into-your-website-with-their-google-account/

And some SO questions that are similar:

- [Google login in my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810911/google-login-in-my-site)
- [Login to site using Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4874186/899126)
- [Using Google account as Login... what next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693495/using-google-account-as-login-what-next)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593992/how-would-go-about-implementing-a-multiple-account-sign-in-like-google